# Scratch Effect Plugin: getting the scratch to go across multiple panels without lifting mouse

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling, mouseevent, jquery

I'm using the HTML5 [rabid scratch plugin](http://rabidflash.com/html5-scratch-card-effect/) to achieve a grid of little panels that can be scratched off to reveal images behind.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/CeTR8/2/

**Problem:**

When you click and drag over a panel, it scratches that panel but you have to mouseup and mousedown for each panel. I'd like scratch from one to another without having to mouseup and mousedown.

I've tried making the following modifications to trigger on mousemove (if mouse button is also down) and it's somewhat working on safari/chrome in Mac but not in IE9 and probably others..

```
  // Bind downHandler to mousemover instead
  self.theCanvas.bind('mousemove', $.proxy(self.addDownHandler, self));

  // self.theCanvas.bind('mousedown', $.proxy(self.addDownHandler, self));
  // self.theCanvas.bind('mouseup', $.proxy(self.addUpHandler, self));
  // $(window).bind('mouseup', $.proxy(self.addUpHandler, self));

....

  addDownHandler: function (e) {
     // only scratch if mouse down
     if(e.which == 1){
        var self = this;
        self.theCanvas.bind('mousemove', $.proxy(self.mouseMoveHandler, self));
     }
  }
```

Current 
http://jsfiddle.net/CeTR8/3/

Is there a better way to do this that will work across browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/CeTR8/5/

Changed

```
self.theCanvas.bind('mousedown', $.proxy(self.addDownHandler, self));
```

to

```
$(window).bind('mousedown', $.proxy(self.addDownHandler, self));
```

Comment: Thanks. That simple! I had the same problem on mobile so I also bound the `touchmove` to `$(window)` but the problem there is that I can't detect `touchmove` over each of the panels...